# Hang at NET: Registered protocol family 10

Tags: raspberry-pi2, nfs, buildroot

I use buildroot build a tiny system for rpi2. Boot rpi with uboot, load kernel and device tree file with tftp, load rootfs through nfs, but it hangs. The output is below.

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xf00
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.18.16-v7 (max@debian) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140106 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1-4.8-2014.01 - Linaro GCC 2013.11) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jul 24 21:11:38 CST 2016
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc075] revision 5 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x07800000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] enter (8620->f3003010)
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] ncores=4
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 10 pages/cpu @876c4000 s11456 r8192 d21312 u40960
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 32512
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: earlyprintk console=ttyAMA0 console=tty1 root=/dev/nfs ip=192.168.0.101 nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/home/max/Project/rpi2_lab/nfsroot rw
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 512 (order: -1, 2048 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 112436K/131072K available (5756K kernel code, 400K rwdata, 1756K rodata, 388K init, 763K bss, 18636K reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xffe00000   (2048 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0x88800000 - 0xff000000   (1896 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0x88000000   ( 128 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0x80008000 - 0x8075e434   (7514 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0x8075f000 - 0x807c0000   ( 388 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0x807c0000 - 0x8082404c   ( 401 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0x8082404c - 0x808e2f94   ( 764 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:608
[    0.000000] Architected cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (phys).
[    0.000013] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 3579139424256ns
[    0.000039] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 52ns
[    0.000341] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001659] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.001708] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=192000)
[    0.001790] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.002186] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.002246] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.003505] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.003594] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.003648] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.003712] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.003762] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[    0.003873] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.003987] ftrace: allocating 19735 entries in 58 pages
[    0.052741] CPU0: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.052822] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 15, mpidr 80000f00
[    0.052863] [bcm2709_smp_prepare_cpus] enter
[    0.053014] Setting up static identity map for 0x530cf8 - 0x530d2c
[    0.112668] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:1 started (0) 18
[    0.112970] CPU1: Booted secondary processor
[    0.112978] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:1
[    0.113034] CPU1: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.113043] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 15, mpidr 80000f01
[    0.132647] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:2 started (0) 18
[    0.132893] CPU2: Booted secondary processor
[    0.132900] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:2
[    0.132933] CPU2: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.132942] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 15, mpidr 80000f02
[    0.152685] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:3 started (0) 16
[    0.152915] CPU3: Booted secondary processor
[    0.152924] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:3
[    0.152955] CPU3: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.152964] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 15, mpidr 80000f03
[    0.153053] Brought up 4 CPUs
[    0.153174] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (153.60 BogoMIPS).
[    0.153207] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.153234] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.154219] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.179040] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 7 rev 5
[    0.181030] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.184080] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.189530] DMA: preallocated 4096 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.190536] bcm2709.uart_clock = 3000000
[    0.193684] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.193740] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.193800] mailbox: Broadcom VideoCore Mailbox driver
[    0.193935] bcm2708_vcio: mailbox at f300b880
[    0.194298] bcm_power: Broadcom power driver
[    0.194337] bcm_power_open() -> 0
[    0.194364] bcm_power_request(0, 8)
[    0.219620] bcm_mailbox_read -> 00000080, 0
[    0.219653] bcm_power_request -> 0
[    0.219794] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.219938] dev:f1: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 83, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev3
[    0.709149] console [ttyAMA0] enabled
[    0.785724] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.789741] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.795415] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.800872] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.807688] Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.843378] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.846630] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.861272] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.866979] TCP established hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.874035] TCP bind hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.880480] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 1024 bind 1024)
[    0.886930] TCP: reno registered
[    0.890209] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.896085] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.902696] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.907769] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.913711] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.918473] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.923191] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.930490] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    0.938913] bcm2708_dma: DMA manager at f3007000
[    0.943701] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x00000000 mem_size:0x00000000(0 MiB)
[    0.953309] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.959778] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.965250] audit: type=2000 audit(0.779:1): initialized
[    0.987025] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    0.991388] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    1.000929] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    1.007325] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    1.012519] Key type id_resolver registered
[    1.016716] Key type id_legacy registered
[    1.021994] msgmni has been set to 235
[    1.027570] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    1.035233] io scheduler noop registered
[    1.039216] io scheduler deadline registered
[    1.043842] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    1.051214] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA memory c7c00000
[    1.056239] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA channel 4 @ f3007400
[    1.069026] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x30
[    1.081941] bcm2708-dmaengine bcm2708-dmaengine: Load BCM2835 DMA engine driver
[    1.091651] uart-pl011 dev:f1: no DMA platform data
[    1.099124] vc-cma: Videocore CMA driver
[    1.105018] vc-cma: vc_cma_base      = 0x00000000
[    1.111701] vc-cma: vc_cma_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    1.119017] vc-cma: vc_cma_initial   = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    1.138305] brd: module loaded
[    1.149082] loop: module loaded
[    1.154796] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0x87c80000, is_master = 0
[    1.164334] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    1.172046] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.179712] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.387571] Core Release: 2.80a
[    1.392504] Setting default values for core params
[    1.399110] Finished setting default values for core params
[    1.606883] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    1.612020] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.619688] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.627035] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    1.633183] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    1.638758] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1047: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = 0x87c14000 dma = 0xc7c14000 len=9024
[    1.652457] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
[    1.652457] Non-periodic Split Transactions
[    1.652457] Periodic Split Transactions
[    1.652457] High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
[    1.676889] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:412: FIQ on core 1 at 0x803dea3c
[    1.684697] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:413: FIQ ASM at 0x803ded98 length 36
[    1.692845] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:438: MPHI regs_base at 0x8880a000
[    1.700765] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.707632] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.716898] dwc_otg bcm2708_usb: irq 32, io mem 0x00000000
[    1.724444] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    1.730332] Init: Power Port (0)
[    1.735715] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.744488] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.753683] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.760328] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.18.16-v7 dwc_otg_hcd
[    1.768298] usb usb1: SerialNumber: bcm2708_usb
[    1.775638] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.781420] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.788176] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.796373] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.804525] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=600000 max=900000
[    1.811614] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.819718] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.826245] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: mmc-bcm2835: Unable to initialise DMA channels. Falling back to PIO
[    1.878023] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.890701] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.899019] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.908891] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.917562] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.923880] TCP: cubic registered
[    1.930377] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    1.937859] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.944435] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.950940] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.958605] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.964890] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    1.965360] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    1.967514] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0001
[    1.968238] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 SD8GB 7.27 GiB 
[    1.972935]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    2.000382] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    2.006472] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    2.014172] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    2.187774] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    2.196438] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    2.398072] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
[    2.406856] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.416864] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.422683] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    2.707816] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    2.828046] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    2.836842] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.848859] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[    2.911753] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, 12:3a:57:23:f2:2e
[    3.090398] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[    4.566372] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
[    4.597728] IP-Config: Guessing netmask 255.255.255.0
[    4.605127] IP-Config: Complete:
[    4.610583]      device=eth0, hwaddr=12:3a:57:23:f2:2e, ipaddr=192.168.0.101, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=255.255.255.255
[    4.625541]      host=192.168.0.101, domain=, nis-domain=(none)
[    4.633711]      bootserver=255.255.255.255, rootserver=192.168.0.1, rootpath=
[    4.650420] VFS: Mounted root (nfs filesystem) on device 0:13.
[    4.659302] devtmpfs: mounted
[    4.665275] Freeing unused kernel memory: 388K (8075f000 - 807c0000)
[    5.111631] random: dd urandom read with 112 bits of entropy available
[    5.610645] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    5.736051] NET: Registered protocol family 10
```

I have waited a long time still no output after 'NET: Registered protocol family 10'.